# Is it possible to add services in a different project in .net core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

My solution has 6 projects and I have a seperate project for data access, my data access project contains the `DbContext` but I want DbContext in my startup class as well for the `AddIdentity`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //I dont have access to DbContext in this project
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services.AddSingleton<ILoginService, LoginService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthService, AuthService>();
}
```

I can think of two possible solutions to this problem

1. To somehow access `DbContext` in `Startup.cs` but I have created a separate data access project and I think it would kind of break the whole purpose of having separate projects.
2. To add the `services.AddIdentity` in a project where `DbContext` is available but I am not sure that is even possible?

What is the best approach to solve this problem? Or can I add `services.AddIdentity` without having to access `DbContext`?

Comment: If you created separate project, you should consider that the project containing the startup.cs is the one that knows everything (it should have all references).  Then, adding the dbcontext there is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The project that contains the `Startup` class is the [composition-root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) of every ASP.NET Core project.

It is meant to be used to configure all services and dependencies and therefor has to have all references necessary.

If you want libraries to contain only interfaces and other libraries implementing those interfaces, that is not a problem as well and also meant to be done that way.

Microsoft does it the same way for instance with the Logging-Library [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/Logging). They always have abstractions, that only contain the so called `Contract`. Then there is another implementation project that uses the contracts. When registering `ILoggerFactory` and `ILogger<TCategory>` within the composition-root a dependent library can rely only on the abstractions and therefor only needs to reference the project [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/) and then injects `ILogger<TCategory>`.

In your case the `ApplicationDbContext` derives from `DbContext`.

You can register it in the composition-root to be resolvable as `DbContext` rather than your derived class by adding this line.

`services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext, DbContext>() // mor config here`

Now a service can inject the `DbContext` and query from it using the generic method `DbContext.Set<TEntity>`

If you need more concrete examples on how to do that, feel free to clone one of my [pet-projects](https://github.com/alsami/etdb-userservice-aspnet-core).

Comment: Great answer also loved the post you referenced about composition root, if we go through that post we find an example about MARY'S APPLICATION, that is basically the kind of architecture I am currently working with in .Net but now I want to replicate that architecture in .Net Core.

Comment: The Composition Root is a new concept to me and as far as my understanding goes, I think its the startup point of the application and it has references to all the projects. I am still a little confused about the request lifecycle of the application, if we think of a simple web application, an incoming request is like `user interface` -> `domain` -> `data access` but what is the request lifecycle of a web application based on the composition root pattern?

Comment: I think what you are referring to are the registration scopes of dependencies. In .NET Core there are only 3 types left: Scoped - one instance per request and disposed when request completed, Transient - one instance per requesting class of a dependency never disposed but not reused after a request completed, Singleton - one instance for the whole application lifetime. You can read more about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes